# Docker deploy my Strongloop Loopback Node server

Tags: docker, strongloop, dockerfile, rancher

I'd like to dockerize my Strongloop Loopback based Node server and start using Process Manager(PM) to keep it running.

I've been using RancherOS on AWS which rocks.

I copied (but didn't add anything to) the following Dockerfile as a template for my own Dockerfile:
https://hub.docker.com/r/strongloop/strong-pm/~/dockerfile/

I then:

```
docker build -t somename .
```

(Dockerfile is in .)

It now appears in:

```
docker images
```

But when I try to start it, exits right away:

```
docker run --detach --restart=no --publish 8701:8701 --publish 3001:3001 --publish 3002:3002 --publish 3003:3003 somename
```

AND if I run the strong-pm image and after opening ports on AWS, it works as above with strongloop/strong-pm not somename

(I can browse aws-instance:8701/explorer)

Also, these instructions to deploy my app https://strongloop.com/strongblog/run-create-node-js-process-manager-docker-images/ require:

```
slc deploy http://docker-host:8701/
```

but Rancher doesn't come with npm (or curl) installed and when I bash into the vm, slc isn't installed, so seems like slc needs to be "outside" the vm

```
docker exec -it fb94ddab6baa bash
```

If you're still reading, nice.  I think I'm trying to add a Dockerfile to my git repo that will deploy my app server (including pulling code from repos) on any docker box.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow for the strongloop/strong-pm docker image assumes you are deploying to it from a workstation. The footprint for `npm install -g strongloop` is significantly larger than strong-pm alone, which is why the docker image has only strong-pm installed in it.